# Python regex: find and replace commas between quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

I have a string,

```
line = '12/08/2013,3,"9,25",42:51,"3,08","12,9","13,9",159,170,"3,19",437,'
```

and I would like to find and replace the commas, between quotation marks, with ":".
Looking for a results

```
line = '12/08/2013,3,9:25,42:51,3:08,12:9,13:9,159,170,3:19,437,'
```

So far I have been able to match this pattern with,

```
import re
re.findall('(\"\d),(.+?\")', line)
```

however, I guess I should be using

```
re.compile(...something..., line)
re.sub(':', line)
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
thanks, labjunky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '12/08/2013,3,"9,25",42:51,"3,08","12,9","13,9",159,170,"3,19",437,'
>>> re.sub(r'"(\d+),(\d+)"', r'\1:\2', line)
'12/08/2013,3,9:25,42:51,3:08,12:9,13:9,159,170,3:19,437,'
```

`\1`, `\2` refer to matched groups.

---

Non-regex solution:

```
>>> ''.join(x if i % 2 == 0 else x.replace(',', ':')
            for i, x in enumerate(line.split('"')))
'12/08/2013,3,9:25,42:51,3:08,12:9,13:9,159,170,3:19,437,'
```

Comment: there is a last detail i think, in the expected op's result the `"` are dropped

Comment: Put the "s outside of the ()'s, OP doesn't want the quotation marks after replacing the ,s with :s.

Comment: @FoxMaSk, Paul McGuire, Thank you for comment. I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
line = '12/08/2013,3,"9,25",42:51,"3,08","12,9","13,9",159,170,"3,19",437,'
r = ""
for t in re.split(r'("[^"]*")', line):
    if t[0] == '"': 
        t = t.replace(",", ":")[1:-1]
    r += t
print r
```

*Prints:*

```
12/08/2013,3,9:25,42:51,3:08,12:9,13:9,159,170,3:19,437,
```

Comment: This only works if there is a comma at the end of the line, like there is in your example.  How to do this if there might not be a comma at the end?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a generic regex solution to replace any kind of fixed (and non-fixed, too) pattern in between double (or single) quotes: match the double- or single quoted substrings with the corresponding pattern, and use a callable as the replacement argumet to `re.sub` where you may manipulate the match:

1. Replacing commas in between double quotes with colons and *remove* the double quotes (the current OP scenario):

   `re.sub(r'"([^"]*)"', lambda x: x.group(1).replace(',', ':'), line)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/zPQsHK))
   `# => 12/08/2013,3,9:25,42:51,3:08,12:9,13:9,159,170,3:19,437,`
2. Replacing  commas in between double quotes with colons and *keep* the double quotes:

   `re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group(0).replace(',', ':'), line)` ([demo](https://ideone.com/aCgIpq))
   `# => 12/08/2013,3,"9:25",42:51,"3:08","12:9","13:9",159,170,"3:19",437,`
3. Replacing  commas in between double *and single* quotes with colons and *keep* the single/double quotes:

   `re.sub(r''''[^']*'|"[^"]*"''', lambda x: x.group(0).replace(',', ':'), '''0,1,"2,3",'4,5',''')` ([demo](https://ideone.com/ZDOjg6))
   `# => 0,1,"2:3",'4:5',`

Also, if you need to handle escaped single and double quotes, consider using `r"'[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'"` (for single quoted substrings), `r'"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"'` (for double quoted substrings) or for both - `r''''[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"'''` instead of the patterns above.