# Regex replace: skip text inside quotes (Python)

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am trying to replace all : by = except the : inside the quotes. In other words: replace all : which are not surrounded by "something and something".

```
# input
x:123; y:"z:456"

# desired output
x=123; y="z:456"
```

I tried to solve this using negative lookbehind/lookahead, but I cannot match the text surrounding the : in the quotes, as quantifiers are not allowed in the lookbehind; so this does not work:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!".+?):(?!.+?")', '$')
```

Can this be done using regex at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a capture group with an alternation using re.sub

In the callback check for capture group 1. If it is there, return it. Else return a `=`

```
("[^"]*")|:
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UX6NsE/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cnYrQ4)

```
import re

pattern = r'("[^"]*")|:'
s = 'x:123; y:"z:456"'

res = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else "=", s)
print(res)
```

Output

```
x=123; y="z:456"
```

Comment: Cools solution. Works for me. Thanks!    BTW: For others interested in this: A similar use case was actually discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110671/replace-comma-outside-double-quote-python-regex) (which I did not find initially).